# Android вложенная навигация

Tags: android, navigation

Как правильно реализовать вложенную навигацию с Android Navigation? Например, если у нас есть 2 фрагмента, внешний и внутренний с 2 навигационными графами. Как я могу правильно перемещаться (получить navigation controller) по внешнему фрагменту из внутреннего?

[Пример кода на github](https://github.com/MakcNmyc/NestedNavigationSample?organization=MakcNmyc&organization=MakcNmyc)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Честно говоря про это вообще не задумывался вызывал волшебную функцию findNavController() и переходил куда надо.

Comment: @MadokaMagica если графа 2 (как на рисунке) то волшебная функция при обращении из внутреннего фрагмента вернет контролер внутреннего графа, а не внешнего. Вообще буду рад услышать даже и другой способ подобной навигации без заморочек.

Comment: Ой я не подскажу ка правильно. Я понял там граф внутри фрагмента или что то типа такого, но я бы не создавал такое. Есть активность и там 1 граф (по графу на активность) и этого в 98% хватает.